# UIWebView is not displaying (Swift)

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I am just trying to create a simple webview inside a view controller.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class test:UIViewController{
@IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var myString = "http://www.google.com"
    let myURL = NSURL(string: myString)
    let myReq = NSURLRequest(URL: myURL)
    myWebView.loadRequest(myReq)

    println(myWebView.loading)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

I'm not getting any errors, simply a white screen. The loading check returns false. It seems like it should be the outlet connection, but I am sure I've made the proper connection. I ctrl-dragged the blue UIWebView element from storyboard into the class as the UIWebView! object and named it myWebView. The circle is filled in on the swift file indicating a connection, and they match up in the connections on the storyboard.

This code originally worked fine for me, but now it does not. I tried creating a completely new project and it still is not working. Adding the UIWebViewDelegate protocol to the class didn't work I've looked at the solutions on the following links, but they do not apply:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898113/uiwebview-do-not-display-contents-in-ios)

[link2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1699)

I'm out of ideas. Anyone got anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you wan in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var myWeb = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 100, width: 240, height: 128))

    var myString = "http://www.google.com"
    let myURL = NSURL(string: myString)
    let myReq = NSURLRequest(URL: myURL!)
    myWeb.loadRequest(myReq)
    view.addSubview(myWeb)

    println(myWeb.loading)
}
```

Be careful, you have another web view (called myWebView) from the storyboard, as an outlet and that is not used. By writing the above code you create a new web view programmatically (called myWeb).

Comment: Oh sorry, I actually meant to comment that part out, as that was something I also tried. I've tried it both ways, but neither seems to work.

Comment: If you copy paste the code above, you will get an UIWebView on screen :)